# Laravel Sanctum impossible to login with Postman

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-sanctum

I've setup Laravel to use a custom 'SESSION_DOMAIN' and 'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS'. However I can't use Postman to login. What I did:

- make GET request to '/sanctum/csrf-cookie'- save XSRF cookie value in an environment variable: xsrfToken
- added header X-XSRF-TOKEN with the value being {{xsrfToken}}

Every time I make the post request I get:"Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException: The payload is invalid. in file ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php on line 195"
And if I try it without the X-XSRF-TOKEN header I get a 419 Page Expired error. Anyone came across this problem? There seems to be no answer to my question yet when google searching.

Comment: try make session driver to cookie in .env file

Comment: @TEFO Could you elaborate why that could fix the problem?

Comment: because you wanna use cookies but the default is file, but its hard to make it work in postman.

Comment: @TEFO Hmm yeah, but why wouldn't it be specified in the docs?

Comment: it is specified in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-authentication . as you can see said ```Sanctum uses Laravel's built-in cookie based session authentication services```

Comment: @TEFO Ok yeah, but it doesn't make sense to me why it wouldn't be in the configuration part of the docs.

Comment: You have to get the sanctum cookie first. Then send the cookie on X-XSRF-TOKEN header. Here is a smart implementation of that: [Laravel Sanctum (Airlock) with Postman](https://morioh.com/p/ed58563aa67a)

Comment: Also having similar problems using Insomnia client

Comment: did you manage to solve it and how?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

- *Optional, but recommended:* you have to create the environment-variable `url` insert the URL of you Laravel-Installation. 
  **Important:** the URL of the pre-request script has to be the same as the effective call (e.g. `{{url}}/login`)
- copy this code-snippet inside the "Pre-request Script" section of your request in Postman (if you have more than one requests, which needs the crsf-token you can also insert it in the collection). This script will save the csrf-token in the environment-variable `xsrf-cookie`

```
pm.sendRequest({
     url: pm.environment.get("url") + '/sanctum/csrf-cookie',
     method: 'GET'
 }, function(error, response, {cookies}) {
     if(!error){
         pm.environment.set('xsrf-cookie', cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN').slice(0,-1))
     }    
})
```

- you API-call (e.g. `{{url}}/login`) has then to contain the following headers:
  `X-XSRF-TOKEN` => `{{xsrf-cookie}}`
  `Accept` => `application/json`
  `Referer`  => `{{url}}`
- and then have fun sanctum and Postman ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the last characters from the CSRF string if it contain "%3D".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

The **request** you are sending to server like

> POST 127.0.0.1:8000/login

and the pre-request url should match